# Ask Customer for Self Shipping?

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

Can we ask Customer if he like the shipping service or can pick the goods from the merchant shop ? If candidate choose to pick goods from merchant shop than i do not want to show customer the delivery option and method on checkout page.

Comment: Where do you want to ask Customer regarding the shipping type like store pickup(Merchant store) or any shipping service?  There are some third party addon available in the Marketplace for store pickup shipping method which will be displayed on the checkout page.

Comment: Hi Imran, thank you for responding, i would like to show it on checkout page, as delivery method option, about the third party extension, yes i know but i heard magento2 have the store pickup module developed, just wondering about how to enable it.